# According to the condition, don't proceed with the remaining script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to validate the Win10 upgrade result by powershell script remotely.

I built this code, and run Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\validate.ps1 -ComputerName remotePC

my question is, if OS edition is win10 ,proceed with the remaining validation.

if OS is win7,  don't proceed with the remaining validation. Any help please? thanks a lot.

```
#Auto-validate the Win10 upgrade result

# Get PC name
$PCname = $env:computername

# Check OS Edition
$OSEdition = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).name

if ($OSEdition -match '10') {
   Write-Host "$PCname Win10" -ForegroundColor Green
   }     
   else {
   Write-Host "$PCname Win7" -ForegroundColor Red
   }

# System Locale
$locale = (Get-WinSystemLocale).Name
if ($locale -eq 'US') {
   Write-Host "$PCname locale is correct" -ForegroundColor Green
   } 
   else {
   Write-Host "$PCname locale is wrong" -ForegroundColor Red
   }

# Check printer status
Get-Printer | Format-Table ComputerName,Name,DriverName,PrinterStatus
```

Comment: Just `return` :)

Comment: I'm still a beginner， could you please provide more information. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to end execution in the current scope (the current function or script), use the `return` keyword, causing PowerShell to return control to the caller:

```bsh
if($OSEdition -notmatch '10'){
  # OS Name doesn't contain '10', let's return!
  return
}
```

For version detection, I'd suggest looking at the `Version` property of `Win32_OperatingSystem` instead of the OS Name:

```bsh
$OSVersion = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version

if($OSVersion -notlike '10.*'){
  return
}
```

To learn more about the `return` keyword, check out the [`about_Return` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return)!

Comment: @bestsinger Great to hear! If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted"!